# Do while loop skipping in c

Tags: c, do-while

I'm still a beginner in c and I'm having trouble with this do-while loop here. It runs smoothly the first time but after i choose yes in try again. it skips the scanf for destination. it will only continue if i entered a number for the number of passengers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

char destination=' ';
int cash=' ';
int passenger=' ';
int multiply;
char again;
int change;
main(){
do{

printf("enter destination : \n");
printf("[Q] Quezon\n");
printf("[K] Kamuning\n");
printf("[A] Araneta Center Cubao\n");
printf("[G] Gilmore\n");
printf("[L] Legarda\n");
printf("[S] Santolan\n");

scanf("%c",&destination);
    int fare;

    switch(destination){
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            printf("Quezon city\n\n");
            fare = 11;

        break;
        case 'k':
        case 'K':
            printf("Kamuning\n\n");
            fare = 13;
        break;

        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            printf("Araneta Center Cubao\n\n");
            fare = 14;
        break;

        case 'G':
        case 'g':

            printf("Gilmore\n\n");
            fare = 16;
        break;

        case 'L':
        case 'l':

            printf("Legarda\n\n");
            fare = 20;
        break;

        case 's':
        case 'S':
            printf("Santolan\n\n");
            fare = 25;
        break;

    }



printf("Enter number of passenger\n");
scanf("%d",&passenger);

multiply = passenger*fare;

printf("\nTotal price: %d",multiply);

printf("\nEnter cash: ");
scanf("%d",&cash);
change=cash-multiply;

if(change<0){

printf ("\nchange: %d",change);
printf ("\nNot enough cash ");
}

else {
    printf ("\nchange: %d",change);
    printf ("\nSuccess");

}
printf("\n\n\nTry again? [y/n]: \n\n\n");
printf("---------------------------------------");
scanf("%s",&again);

}
while(again== 'Y' || again == 'y'|| change<0);
getch();
```

}

Comment: Note that the `'\n'` character does flush the output buffer in normal circumstances so it's more natural (*or customary*) to put it at the end of a line, not at the beginning.

Comment: @xing, actually another one is required `scanf(" %c", &destination);`. I was hoping that the OP would read the documentation and figure this out by himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `scanf()` is a horrible function!

In this case, a `'\n'` was left in the input stream; when you execute `scanf()` again it consumes it and continues with the next one. You might be able to check that `destination` is indeed `'\n'` after the first iteration.

Note that `scanf()` is well designed; it's just not intuitive and that's why I say it's horrible, because it's incredibly difficult to use it correctly.

Most books teach taking input with `scanf()` and none of them explains how it works fully or how it should be used if you were to use it at all.  Read this please [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), but read it thoroughly. You will then notice that `scanf("%d", &value)` without checking what it returns, is simply wrong.

Comment: There are some design decisions in `scanf()` that would be changed in the light of experience. Notable design changes would fix problems with buffer lengths. If you have `char buffer[256];`, you have to use `"%255s"` (rather than `"%256s"`) for the size, whereas almost everywhere else, you use the size of the buffer, not one less than the size of the buffer. And there should be some mechanism to allow you specify the size dynamically, like there is in `printf()` — but `scanf()` pre-empted `*` to suppress assignment, so it's hard to be consistent with `printf()`. These issues can't be fixed.